# Symfony: Storing sessions in JSON

Tags: php, json, symfony, session, redis

In my Symfony application, I'm using NodeJS & socket.io to build a chat feature and send real-time notifications. For this, I'm using Redis to store sessions in JSON format so it can be easily parsed in Javascript.

```
public function read($session_id) {
    $tmp = $_SESSION;
    $_SESSION = json_decode($this->client->get(self::PREFIX . $session_id), true);

    if (isset($_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION) && $_SESSION != null) {
        $encoded_data = session_encode();
        $_SESSION = $tmp;

        return $encoded_data;
    }

    return '';
}

public function write($session_id, $session_data) {
    $tmp = $_SESSION;
    session_decode($session_data);
    $decoded_data = $_SESSION;
    $_SESSION = $tmp;

    $this->client->setex(self::PREFIX . $session_id, $this->ttl, json_encode($decoded_data));

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that the session is not being correctly encoded, especially the user info (authentication part).

**Symfony stored session:**

```
"_sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:18:\"_csrf/authenticate\";s:43:\"Fc3iwpceqYiNmAn1FbUyQyaEPdu7qbI_unu5dBAgaTg\";s:14:\"_security_main\";s:456:\"C:74:\"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Authentication\\Token\\UsernamePasswordToken\":368:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;s:4:\"main\";i:2;s:328:\"a:4:{i:0;C:21:\"AppBundle\\Entity\\User\":127:{a:5:{i:0;i:52;i:1;s:12:\"user123\";i:2;s:60:\"$2y$13$mgT//whXPFsj7b0XCAWhdeiC2oGZqojiAzky.6sThuN6MI9zALt1.\";i:3;i:1;i:4;i:1;}}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:1:{i:0;O:41:\"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Role\\Role\":1:{s:47:\"\x00Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Role\\Role\x00role\";s:9:\"ROLE_USER\";}}i:3;a:0:{}}\";}}\";}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:\"u\";i:1524485577;s:1:\"c\";i:1524485576;s:1:\"l\";s:1:\"0\";}"
```

**JSON encoded session:**

```
"{\"_sf2_attributes\":{\"_csrf\\/authenticate\":\"hvNt4SQIm7IArE57JgHyuVSCLlt4hrw1D-PVC_kBfKA\",\"_security_main\":\"C:74:\\\"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\Security\\\\Core\\\\Authentication\\\\Token\\\\UsernamePasswordToken\\\":368:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;s:4:\\\"main\\\";i:2;s:328:\\\"a:4:{i:0;C:21:\\\"AppBundle\\\\Entity\\\\User\\\":127:{a:5:{i:0;i:52;i:1;s:12:\\\"user123\\\";i:2;s:60:\\\"$2y$13$mgT\\/\\/whXPFsj7b0XCAWhdeiC2oGZqojiAzky.6sThuN6MI9zALt1.\\\";i:3;i:1;i:4;i:1;}}i:1;b:1;i:2;a:1:{i:0;O:41:\\\"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\Security\\\\Core\\\\Role\\\\Role\\\":1:{s:47:\\\"\\u0000Symfony\\\\Component\\\\Security\\\\Core\\\\Role\\\\Role\\u0000role\\\";s:9:\\\"ROLE_USER\\\";}}i:3;a:0:{}}\\\";}}\"},\"_sf2_flashes\":[],\"_sf2_meta\":{\"u\":1524651793,\"c\":1524651793,\"l\":\"0\"}}"
```

Doesn't Symfony use the PHP built-in storage mechanism? What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check this bundle ? https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to store in session: In your client entity implement \Serializable and then write the serialize and unserialize functions example:

```
class Client implements \Serializable{
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize([
        $this->id,
        $this->name,
        $this->color
    ]);
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->name,
        $this->color
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}}
```

after this you can almost everywhere use it like this

```
$this->session->set('client',$client);
$this->session->get('client');
```

add any other required fields you want to serialize and unserialize functions

Comment: Implement \Serializable class on User entity?

Comment: indeed, i just added client since you used client

Comment: implement serializable to any entity you want to store in session, user, client etc...

Comment: $this->client here is the redis client (predis). How will this solve my actual problem of reading the session data in javascript?

Comment: yeah my bad, forgot about the redis. then yeah implement serializable to user entity this should fix it

Comment: i will edit the answer soon when i am back on my machine

Comment: How will it solve my actual problem of reading the session data in javascript?

Comment: serilazing always work with this kind of issues: refer to this please https://gist.github.com/pulse00/4204440